# Get Current year and next form mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Im am selecting various things from a table. The problem is I only want to select them if they belong to the current year and the next year.

My table looks like this

> Title         Text         Date

The date is formated like this 0000-00-00 and is in the format "date"

So the question is how can i select only items from only this year and the next?

Example: the year is 2012, I have items in my table that is old and i dont want them to show - I only want to select items from at the first 2012 1 January and last in this case 31 Dec 2013 current year 2012 + 1 year.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 69, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  table 
WHERE 
  YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
OR 
  YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) + 1
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Note however, that this will not use index on `date` field.

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM
  table
WHERE
  date BETWEEN CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()),'-01-01') AND CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE())+1,'-12-31')
```

As ugly as it looks, it allows your query to use index on `date` field.

Better idea is to create limiting dates in external PHP script, so that the query can use query cache.

---

If you only want to show items, that are no older than two years, you can do this:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  table
WHERE
  date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 YEAR;
```