# SQL - Get result of current year only

Tags: mysql, sql, date

How can I get the result of the current year using SQL?

I have a table that has a column date with the format `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Now, I want to do select query that only returns the current year result.

The pseudo code should be like:

```
select * from table where date is (current year dates)
```

The result should be as following:

```
id date
2  2015-01-01
3  2015-02-01
9  2015-01-01
6  2015-02-01
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Current year and next form mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811271/get-current-year-and-next-form-mysql)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Use [`YEAR()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) to get only the year of the dates you want to work with:

```
select * from table where YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

Comment: it works thanks. how about specific year. e.g. how to define date=2015 year result only

Comment: Change `YEAR(CURDATE())` to `2015`

Answer (score 11):

When I tried these answers on SQL server, I got an error saying curdate() was not a recognized function.

If you get the same error, using getdate() instead of curdate() should work!

Answer (score 10):

Using `WHERE YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE())` is correct but it cannot use an index on column `date` if exists; if it doesn't exist it should.

A better solution is:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-12-31'
```

The dates (first and last day of the year) need to be generated from the client code.

Comment: The best answers. Yet it is wrong when the `date` column contains a time component (which is not the case, as per the original question). Yet, something to consider. See here for a discussion: https://modern-sql.com/feature/extract#anit-patter-where-clause

Answer (score 3):

--========= Get Current Year ===========

```
Select DATEPART(yyyy, GETDATE())
```

Comment: `select year( getdate() )` is a bit simpler and achieves the same result

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT id, date FROM your_table WHERE YEAR( date ) = YEAR( CURDATE() )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    date
FROM
    TABLE
WHERE
    YEAR (date) = YEAR (CURDATE());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using SQL `DATE_FORMATE()`. like below:

```
SELECT
    date
FROM
    TABLE
WHERE
    DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y') = YEAR (CURDATE());
```

Answer (score 1):

If the date field contains a time component, you want to include December 31 so you have to go to January 1 of the next year. You also don't have to use code to insert dates into the SQL. You can use the following

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE date BETWEEN MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE()), 1) AND MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE())+1, 1)
```

This will give you January 1st of the current year through January 1st at midnight of the following year.

As @Clockwork-Muse pointed out, if the date field does not contain a time component, you would want to exclude January 1 of the following year by using

```
WHERE date >= MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE()), 1) AND date < MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE())+1, 1)
```

Comment: `BETWEEN` is upper bound inclusive - `<=` - so if there's a time component this would include `yyyy-01-01 00:00:00` entries.  An explicit upper bound should be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [ID]
       ,[datefield]
FROM [targettable]
WHERE DATEPART(YYYY, [datefield]) = (SELECT TOP 1(MAX(DATEPART(YYYY, [datefield])))
                                FROM [targettable]
                               )
/*
This will find the newest records in the table regardless of how recent the last time data was entered.
 To grab the oldest records from the table do this
   SELECT [ID]
       ,[datefield]
   FROM [targettable]
   WHERE DATEPART(YYYY, [datefield]) = (SELECT TOP 1(MIN(DATEPART(YYYY, [datefield])))
                                       FROM [targettable]
                                       )
```

*/