# I need to select only the 2018 records from the crdd and schedule date

Tags: mysql, amazon-redshift

I need to select only the 2018 records from the crdd and schedule date. This is my current query:

```
Select distinct t1.inbound_ship_appointment_id as ISA,
    t1.STANDARD_CARRIER_ALPHA_CODE as carrier_name,
    t1.current_appt_start as scheduled_date,
    t1.WAREHOUSE_ID as FC,
    t2.carrier_req_del_date_local as crdd,
    datediff(days, t1.current_appt_start , t2.carrier_req_del_date_local)
from d_fc_appointment_details t1
join o_appointment_visibility t2
    on t1.inbound_ship_appointment_id= t2.inbound_ship_appointment_id
where t1.STANDARD_CARRIER_ALPHA_CODE in (
   'AZIM','BTIU','HJBI','HUBG','PGLI','SCDS','SWIF','XAMS','XHMC','XHME',
   'XHMM','XJMN','XJMW') 
   OR t1.STANDARD_CARRIER_ALPHA_CODE LIKE '%IMP%
```

Please advise

Comment: Have you made ANY attempt to restrict the rows selected?

Comment: You'll want to format your code a bit, it's pretty hard to read

Comment: no .. i only want to filter out the 2018 records

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use  get year using this line

```
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM '2008-05-15') As year
```

Comment: I mean I only want to filter out the 2018 values

Comment: hi if you using above code you can get year like (2018) and put it where condition

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
WHERE YEAR(t1.current_appt_start) = YEAR(2018)
```

Since you're using a `or` operator, you would have to:

```
WHERE (
    t1.STANDARD_CARRIER_ALPHA_CODE in ([...]) 
    OR t1.STANDARD_CARRIER_ALPHA_CODE LIKE '%IMP%'
) AND YEAR(t1.current_appt_start) = YEAR(2018)
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27745487/3208151

Comment: Hi thanks. Does the YEAR function works in Redshift?

Comment: You used the `mysql` tag, so it will work with a mysql environment. Please update the tags to read Redshift. If it's for redshift, look at: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATE_PART_YEAR.html

Comment: Jared can you check once now?

Comment: what will be the YEAR function alias in redshift. or how can I filter out the 2018 values in the column crdd and scheduled_date.

Comment: I provided a link to the function above.