# SQL query with date filter but use system year

Tags: mysql

I´m creating a static reports for every month for every year from our ERP database, contract table. I've managed to get everything right but now I have to alter the monthly queries every year. Currently I use this to separate the months:

```
WHERE [Ending Date] >= '04.01.2021' and [Starting Date] <= '04.30.2021'
```

As said the output is right but what I want is the query to use system year, so only dates are input in the query and therefore when the year changes, it would change in the query automatically.

Comment: Need more info, so what will be on day,month part?

Comment: I´m sorry if i´m a bit confusive here but i´ll try: The date and month are both static in every years same month report. Only thing that needs to change in the query is the year. As in example it is 2021 and it should pick up the current year of running the query. So let´s say that i run the query with the date filters above next year, then the year should be filled automatically as 2020.

Comment: Given the MySQL (which I appreciate might be an error), it's nonsensical to suggest that a date might be less than (or greater than) a mal-formatted string such as '04.30.2021' . Store dates using a date data type.

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't too clear, but what I vaguely understood is you want to get the year dynamically (not sure if you want just the year or the whole date) but you can make use of `YEAR()` function (something like `YEAR(CURDATE())` could get you the year of the current date). You can also take a look [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) for more useful functions.

I couldn't form a query or tell you what functions to exactly use because I doubt I'm fully understanding. Some functions you may make use of are `PERIOD_ADD()` and `TIMESTAMPADD()`.

Comment: Thank you. I just want to use the year since i need to know the results before the actual query running date. As a clarification, i´m picking up the agreement amounts separated montly per year, so the whole year has it´s own queries for every month before the actual month so all the year´s monthly reports get updated once a month (i´m probably confusing you even more). I already tried adding the YEAR() to the query but i did not manage to do it properly i guess. I´ll take a look at the list you provided.

Comment: @Machina You might also find this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811271/get-current-year-and-next-form-mysql