# How to dynamically update dates every year for a query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a where clause in a SQL statement that hard codes two dates using a between function. I would like to have those dates be more dynamic and update every year with out manually changing it. Using the GetDate function in some manner.

I have tried using variations of getdate and it does not work.

My current code looks like this

Where Date between '1/1/2018' and 1/1/2019'

I need this to update every year once a a new year starts in January.

Comment: duplicate of [Get Current year and next form mysql
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811271/get-current-year-and-next-form-mysql)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and date time functions are highly vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server I apologize

Comment: I have figured it out using YEAR(GETDATE()) CURDATE does not seem to work for me Thank you all that answered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Where date between (SELECT DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) And
   (DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, -1))
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: In addition to what jarlh wrote: the `select` after the between is completely useless

Comment: In addition to both of the above: your EndDate will exclude all data for the 31st of that year

Answer (score 0):

For MS SQL Server you can use the below for the previous year's data;

```
    WHERE [DateFieldName]   BETWEEN DATEADD(YYYY, DATEDIFF(YYYY, 0, GETDATE()) -1, 0) 
                            AND DATEADD(YYYY, DATEDIFF(YYYY, 0, GETDATE()),0)
```

Answer (score 0):

For MS SQL Server 2012 and later you can use DATEFROMPARTS:

```
DECLARE @StartDate Date = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),1,1)
DECLARE @EndDate Date = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE())+1,1,1)
```

Then your query becomes:

```
SELECT *
FROM SomeTable
WHERE MyDate >= @StartDate AND MyDate < @EndDate
```